# How to process response body of workspace docs export in HTML (mimetype application/zip) from Batch Request of Google Drive API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api, mime-types

I am able to handle the export, in Plain Text, of 100 Google Workspace docs to my server,  for each Google Drive [Batch Request](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/performance#overview).  I have followed Kanshi Tanaike’s excellent examples ["Efficient File Management using Batch Requests with Google Apps Script"](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/efficient-file-management-using-batch-requests-google-apps-script)

However, for Google docs export in HTML (rather than plain text), I do not know how to process the response body.  (BTW, the mime type is application/zip for HTML export).

I am hoping someone can provide some basic information about how to process the response body.  Or perhaps an example in Google Apps Script or Elixir which I could then follow?

I have tried splitting the response body using the batch marker into the 100 requests (as I do with the plain text example).  I am left with what what might be one or 100 zip files but I everything I have tried to unzip them has given an error.  I presume that I am splitting the response.body incorrectly. I am not an experienced programmer and have no experience in working with zip files.  I even tried opening split response.body with unzip utilities without success.

Note that I can handle the response.body of the export of a single workspace doc, in HTML, not within a Batch request, using:

```
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/#{doc_id}/export?mimeType=application/zip"
```

This is because the response is very clearly a set of tuples of either {item_name, text_string)  (for the HTML part or the document, which can be processed directly) or {item_name, byte_sequence} (for, eg, images within the doc).

Actually, I am at the moment only interested in the HTML part rather than images, even in the batch export (is there a way to only export the HTML in a batch request? )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to export multiple Google Documents as `application/zip` with the batch requests using Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- In the current stage, the response value from the batch request is as follows.

  ```
    --batch_###
    Content-Type: application/http
    Content-ID: response-1

    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Content-Disposition: attachment
    Content-Type: application/zip
    Date: ###
    Expires: ###
    Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
    Content-Length: 1000

    ### data ###
    --batch_###--
  ```

  - I think that `### data ###` is the zip file as the binary data. In this case, when the value is retrieved with `res.getContentText()`, the response value is converted to the string value. By this, even when the binary data is retrieved, the retrieved data is broken. I think that this is the reason for your current issue of `but I everything I have tried to unzip them has given an error.`.
- In order to correctly decode the retrieved data, in this case, it is required to process the response data with the binary level. In this case, it is required to process the data with the byte array.

In this answer, I would like to propose a simple sample script for decoding the response data from the batch request (In this case, Google Document files are exported as `application/zip`.).

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of the Google Apps Script project, and please set your folder ID and document IDs.

And, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services.

```js
/**
 * Ref: https://tanaikech.github.io/2023/03/08/split-binary-data-with-search-data-using-google-apps-script/
 * Split byteArray by a search data.
 * @param {Array} baseData Input byteArray of base data.
 * @param {Array} searchData Input byteArray of search data using split.
 * @return {Array} An array including byteArray.
 */
function splitByteArrayBySearchData_(baseData, searchData) {
  if (!Array.isArray(baseData) || !Array.isArray(searchData)) {
    throw new Error("Please give byte array.");
  }
  const search = searchData.join("");
  const bLen = searchData.length;
  const res = [];
  let idx = 0;
  do {
    idx = baseData.findIndex((_, i, a) => [...Array(bLen)].map((_, j) => a[j + i]).join("") == search);
    if (idx != -1) {
      res.push(baseData.splice(0, idx));
      baseData.splice(0, bLen);
    } else {
      res.push(baseData.splice(0));
    }
  } while (idx != -1);
  return res;
}

/**
 * Ref: https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/efficient-file-management-using-batch-requests-google-apps-script
 * Create a request body of batch requests and request it.
 * 
 * @param {Object} object Object for creating request body of batch requests.
 * @returns {Object} UrlFetchApp.HTTPResponse
 */
function batchRequests_(object) {
  const { batchPath, requests } = object;
  const boundary = "sampleBoundary12345";
  const lb = "\r\n";
  const payload = requests.reduce((r, e, i, a) => {
    r += `Content-Type: application/http${lb}`;
    r += `Content-ID: ${i + 1}${lb}${lb}`;
    r += `${e.method} ${e.endpoint}${lb}`;
    r += e.requestBody ? `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" ${lb}${lb}` : lb;
    r += e.requestBody ? `${JSON.stringify(e.requestBody)}${lb}` : "";
    r += `--${boundary}${i == a.length - 1 ? "--" : ""}${lb}`;
    return r;
  }, `--${boundary}${lb}`);
  const params = {
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    method: "post",
    contentType: `multipart/mixed; boundary=${boundary}`,
    headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
    payload,
  };
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/${batchPath}`, params);
}

// Please run this function.
function main() {
  const folderId = "###"; // Please set folder ID you want to put the files.
  // Please set your document Ids.
  const documentIds = [
    "### Document ID1 ###",
    "### Document ID2 ###",
    "### Document ID3 ###",
    ,
    ,
    ,
  ];

  // Run batch requests.
  const requests = documentIds.map((id) => ({
    method: "GET",
    endpoint: `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${id}/export?mimeType=application/zip`,
  }));
  const object = { batchPath: "batch/drive/v3", requests };
  const res = batchRequests_(object);
  if (res.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    throw new Error(res.getContentText());
  }

  // Parse data as binary data, and create the data as Blob.
  const check = res.getContentText().match(/--batch.*/);
  if (!check) {
    throw new Error("Valid response value is not returned.");
  }
  const search = check[0];
  const baseData = res.getContent();
  const searchData = Utilities.newBlob(search).getBytes();
  const res1 = splitByteArrayBySearchData_(baseData, searchData);
  res1.shift();
  res1.pop();
  const blobs = res1.map((e, i) => {
    const rrr = splitByteArrayBySearchData_(e, [13, 10, 13, 10]);
    const data = rrr.pop();
    const metadata = Utilities.newBlob(rrr.flat()).getDataAsString();
    const dataSize = Number(metadata.match(/Content-Length:(.*)/)[1]);
    return Utilities.newBlob(data.splice(0, dataSize)).setName(`sampleName${i + 1}.zip`);
  });

  // Create blobs as the files in Google Drive.
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  blobs.forEach(b => {
    if (b) {
      console.log({ filename: b.getName(), fileSize: b.getBytes().length })
      folder.createFile(b);
    }
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, the zip files including the HTML data converted from Google Documents are created in the folder. And, the sample filenames are `sampleName1.zip`, `sampleName2.zip`, `sampleName3.zip`,,,.

#### Note:

- IMPORTANT: I'm not sure whether this method can be used for 100 batch requests. Because, when the response size is more than 50 MB, an error might occur. I'm worried about this. So, when you test this script, please test the script using a small number of sample Google Documents.
- I noticed `I am at the moment only interested in the HTML part rather than images` just now. As another approach, when `mimeType=application/zip` is changed to `mimeType=text/html`, it seems that only HTML data is included in the response value as the string. In this case, the response data can be parsed as a string.

#### Reference:

- [Efficient File Management using Batch Requests with Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/efficient-file-management-using-batch-requests-google-apps-script)

Comment: @David Tew I updated my sample script. Please confirm it. In the case of my old one, only a zip file could be used. In the case of an updated script, I modified the method for parsing the binary data. By this, for example, when `mimeType=application/zip` is modified to `mimeType=application/pdf`, the PDF files can be retrieved. At that time, please modify the filename of `sampleName${i + 1}.zip` to `sampleName${i + 1}.pdf`.

Comment: this is indeed very comprehensive. I personally thank you. I hope others can be reassured that they can use batch for downloads.  So, I successfully run your original script in GAS.  I have now successfully translated it to work in Elixir too.  Next I shall try text/html, then your revised script (and translate both of these to Elixir too, no doubt).  Thanks again Tanaike!

Comment: I forgot to mention, I will try for pdf too, in GAS (but I doubt it will be straight forward for me to translate into Elixir, since I am a newbie there and I have only learned how to use :zip functions in Elixir so far ... but perhaps Elixir is not your interest!).

Comment: @David Tew Thank you for replying. I could think of a sample script for parsing the response value from batch requests with the binary data from your question. Thank you, too. Now, I don't use Elixir. When I have a chance to use it, I would like to try it.

Comment: fyi.  Test  7 large docs, ranging 150 to 500 pages, not dense text, embedding 5 thumbnails each.  
Zip files created, in order: 556KB, 324KB, 138KB, 324KB, 350KB, 263KB, 714KB
PDF files, same order: error500, 1.1MB, 456KB, 1.7KB, error500, 1.1MB, error500
Above in GAS. 
The script (translated to Elixir) in my local mac, downloaded approx 100 small docs, each with 6 sparse pages of text (mode), none images, in under 2 seconds and then split batch, extracted html from zip and saved html in 100 individual files (median 85KB) locally in a further 0.5s. So under 2.5 secs in total.

Comment: The response body is now, one year later, giving code 302.  Does anyone know if the API has changed?

Comment: @David Tew About `The response body is now, one year later, giving code 302. Does anyone know if the API has changed?`, now, I confirmed it The status code 302 means the redirect. When I checked the export method of Drive API, unfortunately, even when `followRedirects: false` is used, the valid value is returned. From this situation, I'm worried that in the current stage, the export method of Drive API might not be able to be used with the batch request. I deeply apologize for this situation. On the other hand, it seems that the specification of the batch request is not changed.

Comment: oh dear this is quite serious I think.  I hope we get a workaround or another solution from Google. I presume this means that we would need to export documents one-by-one?

Comment: @David Tew Thank you for replying. About `I presume this means that we would need to export documents one-by-one?`, in the current stage, it's yes. I deeply apologize for this situation. When this is resolved, I would like to tell you here. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. I would like to study more.

Comment: Thank you Tanaike for confirming this.  I am happy that you feel that this will be resolved, and I will check here, as you say.

Comment: @David Tew Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for this changed specification.